# How do I push different branches to different heroku apps?

Tags: git, heroku, git-branch, staging, dev-to-production

I've been working on a web-app that gets pushed to heroku. The source is hosted on GitHub.

So `git push` pushes the master branch to GutHub.

My git branch 'master' is connected to Heroku app '`my-app-staging`'

So `git push heroku` pushes the app to `my-app-staging.herokuapp.com`

I've created a new Heroku app which will be the 'production' app, let's call it '`my-app-prod`'.

I have created a branch now called '`production`' (ie `git checkout -b production`) and I've run `git push -u origin production` to make it a managed branch at GitHub.

I now want to link the `production` branch to `my-app-prod.herokuapp.com` such that, when switched to the `production` branch I can simply type `git push heroku` (or perhaps `git push prod-heroku production` or similar) and voila - the production branch is pushed to the production app.

What's the recommended way to link my `production` branch to `my-app-prod` on Heroku?

I've wallowed through [Heroku's own docs on this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps) but they all assume I've set up my apps using the `heroku create` CLI, not set up my apps via Heroku's website, however the following paragraph just makes my head spin:

> It’s simple to type `git push staging master` and `git push production master` when
>   you’ve followed the steps above. Many developers like to take advantage of git’s
>   branches to separate in-progress and production-ready code, however. In this sort
>   of setup, you might deploy to production from your master branch, merging in changes
>   from a development branch once they’ve been reviewed on the staging app. With this
>   setup, pushing is a littler trickier:

Where I want to end up is as follows:

1. In branch `master`: (a) `git push` pushes code to GitHub, and (b) `git push heroku` pushes code to `my-app-staging` on Heroku
2. In branch `production`: (c) `git push` pushes code to the `production` branch on GitHub, and (d) `git push heroku` pushes the `production` code to `my-app-prod` on Heroku.

Given step 1 above is already in place and step 2 (c) is in place, how do I achieve step 2 (d)?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should add another remote for my-app-prod named prod-heroku (replace GIT_URL with the Git URL that you can find in the settings page of my-app-prod in heroku):

```
git remote add prod-heroku GIT_URL
git push prod-heroku production:master
```

This will push your local branch production to the remote branch master in prod-heroku so my-app-prod will get deployed with the code in production branch.

Comment: That's perfect. And voila - there it goes. :-)

Comment: there is a way to match your branch with the heroku pipeline stage so that you don't have to worry about specifying the branch explicitly.

Comment: @BenKoshy - is there a link?